# Is it possible to rename an index using a rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I know that there is a `rename_column` transformation, but it seems that `rename_index` does not exist.

Do I have to use `remove_index` and `add_index` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute arbitrary SQL in your migrations as well.

We have some helper methods that add foreign keys to our tables:

```
def add_foreign_key(from_table, from_column, to_table)
  constraint_name = "fk_#{from_table}_#{from_column}"

  execute %{alter table #{from_table}
            add constraint #{constraint_name}
            foreign key (#{from_column})
            references #{to_table}(id)
           }
  end
```

You can use any SQL your database supports.

Comment: One situation where you might have to use `execute` is if Rails has added an index and named it according to the table name, then you've renamed the table. For example, I created `users_roles` and did a migration to add an index, which Rails named `index_users_roles_on_role_id`. Then I realized I needed to rename the table to `roles_users`. Later when I tried to remove the index, Rails was looking for one called `index_roles_users_on_role_id`. So I had to use `execute "DROP INDEX index_users_roles_on_role_id ON roles_users"` in my migration. (This is for MySQL.)

Answer (score 78):

`rename_index` should be given strings and not symbols when referencing the index name.

```
rename_index :table_name, 'old_name', 'new_name'
```

Had me scratching my head for a while when trying to rename a table and its indexes.  Rails 3.2.3 and MySQL.

Comment: PS: Remember to `rename_index` **before** you `rename_column`, if not then SQLServer will throw an exception: `Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (INDEX) is wrong.`

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use symbols instead of strings for my index names and the `rename_index` operation during my `rake db:migrate` was just silently failing: No error occurred, but the rename didn't happen.

Answer (score 45):

Rails 3 provide a shortcut to rename an index:

```
rename_index :table_name, :old_name, :new_name
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

By the way, it doesn't do more than removing the old one and adding the new one:

http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/rename_index

Comment: rename_index seems to have been added back in 2.3.8, your second link even shows that version.

Comment: rename_index doesn't seem to actually do anything in Rails 3.1.3. The migration appears to run cleanly, but checking both the schema.rb and running `SHOW INDEXES FROM table_name` within MySQL show the index maintaining it's prior name.

Comment: As pointed out in nothus' answer below the index names have to be given as strings or the rename_index call fails silently

Comment: Fixed since 6.1.3 it now support symbol as well !https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/rename_index

Answer (score 26):

As of Rails 5 (EDIT: also in Rails 4), renaming the column will also automatically rename the index.

Comment: This is great! It should be mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah. This question was asked in '09!! 7 year later, a lot has changed. Its automatic now.

Comment: Does it rename the foreign key as well, if there is one?

Comment: Yup, true for Rails 7.0.x as well

Comment: Here is the commit that added this https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/39eef1a565ef02e4dabc0811ef1bf4547ff9a60e

Answer (score 4):

According to the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html), using `remove_index` and `add_index` is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: No longer true. Should it be deleted?